# Delete many items in DynamoDB without effecting active users

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I know that DynamoDB is bound to a writes and read per second limit, which I set. This means that when I delete items they are bound to the same limits. I want to be able to delete many records at some point in time, without that having a negative effect on the other operations that my app is doing.

So for example, if I run a script to delete 10,000 items and it takes 1 minutes, I don't want my database to stop serving other users that are using my app. Is there a way to separate the two, one for background processes (admin) and give it its own limits and one for the main process (the  app)?

Note: The item deletion will be by date ranges, and I have no way in knowing how much items are there ahead of time.

App in ASP.NET C#

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The limits are set on the DynamoDB tables themselves, not on the client requests, so the answer is no.
One workaround is to write a script that:

- increases the write ops limit
- runs the delete queries in a throttled manner so that it uses only the offset between the old limit and the newly set one
- decreases the limit back, after the operations are completed.

You could then optimise the amount by which you scale up the writes/second to balance the time it takes for the script to complete.